# wordpress custom excerpt length not working

Tags: php, wordpress, grid

I have this code in my functions.php

```
function custom_excerpt_length() {

return 15;

}

add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');
```

but it doesn't work as it gives me the full text and not the 15 words I specified. And the grid I have set up on my website is not right because of this.

[my movie grid](http://www.scottiescotsman.com/movies)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add third parameter as priority correctly and you have not pass parameter as on functions then please check your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also use this code for multiple type of getting excerpt

```
function excerpt($limit) {
      $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
      if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
      } else {
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
      } 
      $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
      return $excerpt;
    }

    function content($limit) {
      $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
      if (count($content)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($content);
        $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
      } else {
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
      } 
      $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
      $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
      return $content;
    }
```

then in your template code you just use..

```
<?php echo excerpt(25); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add third parameter and also you have not mention function parameter it will be worked

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 15;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: what is the third parameter for ?

Comment: It's priority correctly for your function priority. And you have forgot to add function parameter like `$length`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem too, your code is right.
To solve this just go to Wordpress dashboard > posts > all posts then click edit in the post that has the problem, in the editor make sure that the excerpt is empty then click update.
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA86l.png)

Comment: If the excerpt is empty nothing will be loaded from the excerpt block. The post will then be used as a source https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/ . If you read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/excerpt_length/ however you see a priority is needed so custom settings do not get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **"Excerpt" block in Gutenberg editor**, and you are trying to set a default length for it (or anything other than the originally allowed 10-100 word value) you may find that the `excerpt_length` filter has no effect on the block, and you can't even use `the_excerpt` filter to override the excerpt's content. This is is because of the [latest updates](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset?sfp_email=&sfph_mail=&reponame=&new=56065%40trunk%2Fsrc%2Fwp-includes%2Fblocks%2Fpost-excerpt.php&old=55246%40trunk%2Fsrc%2Fwp-includes%2Fblocks%2Fpost-excerpt.php) in the Excerpt block in WordPress.

However, you can use the following code to edit the default block settings of the Excerpt Gutenberg block:

```
function filter_metadata_registration( $metadata ) {
    if ($metadata['name'] === 'core/post-excerpt') {
        $metadata['attributes']['excerptLength'] = [
            'type' => 'number',
            'default' => 9999,
        ];
    }
    return $metadata;
};
add_filter( 'block_type_metadata', 'filter_metadata_registration' );
```

More on this: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/59348